# Extra node statuses

Tags: 7, nodes

Working with D7, I want extra statuses for nodes, such as "unpublished," "published," "draft,"  but also "received," "under review," and "approved." What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add additional 'on/off' style switches to an entity or node like Published -> Unpublished and Approve -> Rejected I would recommend looking into the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module.

Answer (score 0):

there is also the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) module if you need more of an editorial flow with approval processes:

> ... a customizable editorial workflow that integrates with the access control feature described above or works independently on its own